# Cmake Commandline parameters only - Linking external library using

Tags: c++, cmake, cmakelists-options

I am new to Cmake and learning. I am using Ubuntu 20

I am not allowed to make changes CMakeLists.txt file. I am trying to use **-DIMPORTED_LOCATION=**/home/map/third_party for linking external library(libdlt.so) which is present in a user-defined location instead of the default location. But with this command, I am getting the following error

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldlt
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Could you please help to clarify why it is not picking this parameter? If this library(libdlt.so) is at default location(/etc/local/lib) then CMake is working correctly.

Thanks
<

Comment: "Could you please help to clarify why it is not picking this parameter?" - You set **variable** named IMPORTED_LOCATION, but location of the library is determined by the **target property** [IMPORTED_LOCATION](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/IMPORTED_LOCATION.html). In CMake variable and property are different things. Not every thing is configurable from the command line. If `CMakeLists.txt` links with `dlt` library by its name, you cannot affect on location of that library via command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this only with command line parameters.

The `IMPORTED_LOCATION` is a target property. This means it only has meaning to CMake when applying it to a CMake target.

Dependencies in CMake usually are managed with imported targets, which has the `IMPORTED_LOCATION` property.

It would be done like this:

```
find_path(DLT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY dlt/dlt.h)
find_library(DLT_LIBRARY NAMES dlt)

add_library(dlt::dlt IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(dlt::dlt PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION ${DLT_LIBRARY}
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${DLT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY}
)

# then, later in your CMake scripts...

target_link_libraries(yourExecutable PUBLIC dlt::dlt)
```

You first find the paths. Include directory and library path.

Then, you create an imported target and set the path as its properties.

**Then** call CMake with the right prefix path so the `find_*` command search in the right directory:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/map/third_party
```

---

Now as you mentionned in the comments, you cannot change the CMakeLists file.

If you're using a library that has this broken CMake script, I would suggest forking it and fix their CMake file to not be hardcoded.

If you insist on not modifying the CMake file, there's a couple of things you can do.

You can create your own `CMakeLists.txt`, and use it instead. Yes you can do that! It is hackish but allows you to have a modifiable `CMakeLists.txt` that you can fix its behavior.

Create a sibling directory to the unmodifiable project, and add a `CMakeLists.txt` in it and a `build/` directory.

In those CMake, use relative paths like this:

```
add_library(yourlib STATIC)
target_sources(yourlib ../yourproject/file1.cpp ../yourproject/file2.cpp)
```

Then, use proper `find_XXX` function so CMake can have a chance to find the right library instead of an hardcoded path.

---

There's another hack, but it's a bit more hackish.

You can replace the link program that CMake uses with a custom one with a command line argument:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_LINKER=/path/to/linker -DCMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE="<CMAKE_LINKER> <FLAGS> <CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS> -o <TARGET> <LINK_LIBRARIES>"
```

You can replace `/path/to/linker` with a script that will replace the hardcoded flags with the good ones instead.

This is *very* hackish. Expect things to break or not behave correctly.

---

If you cannot create a separated CMakeLists script and replacing the link program is not an option either, there's another hack you can do. This is incredibly hackish, hard to create, hard to maintain, beginner unfriendly solution, and also very brittle and can break easily.

I must warn you, this is much worse than applying a patch to a third party library, and this is *much much* worse than creating your own CMake script. I woudln't recommend it to anyone. Also it deals with the worst part of CMake.

You can inject a CMake file in a script using the cmd with [`CMAKE_PROJECT_INCLUDE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_PROJECT_INCLUDE.html):

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_PROJECT_INCLUDE=myfile.cmake
```

In `myfile.cmake`, you can write cmake code.

At that point, you can patch CMake builtin command with a macro to catch the unwanted behaviour and replace it with the wanted one.

```
macro(link_libraries)
    # find and replace in ARGV
endmacro()
```

---

If you cannot write a CMake file replacing CMake commands, I will assume your filesystem is immutable and your bug cannot be fixed ;)

Comment: Is it possible to have any workaround using environment variable if modifying CMakeLists.txt is not allowed?

Comment: If the CMake list that you cannot change is good enough to use `find_XXX` then adding the prefix path in the cmd would to the trick. If this is because of a dependency of yours I would recoment forking and fixing their CMake files. Reading the error, it seems like they have *hardcoded the linking flags*. That means your environment has to be as fixed as it is hardcoded.

Comment: @user1833852 I added a list of hack and patches that you can do. They all won't fix the problem, but may make things work temporarily.